# SwiftUI raw image conversion

Tags: swift, swiftui, photo

There seems to be a difference to the way iPadOS and macOS handle raw image files from digital cameras (tested with Fujifilm X-T3 uncompressed RAF file - included on the compatible list).

Running the following code (with "Rawsample" being the name of a RAF file in Xcode Assets) on the iPad displays the preview jpeg embedded in the RAF file whereas on the mac the raw data are converted:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var image: Image?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            image?
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
        }
        .onAppear(perform: loadImage)
    }

    func loadImage() {
        guard let asset = NSDataAsset(name: "Rawsample") else { return }
        let data = asset.data
        image = Image(uiImage:UIImage(data:data)!)
    }
}
```

Am I missing something or is this the expected behaviour and is it documented somewhere?

Comment: You should not use `AsyncImage` for loading images from local URLs, that view should only be used for loading images from remote URLs. Load the image data using `Data(contentsOf: item.url)` instead and then create the `Image` from a `UIImage` or `NSImage` depending on iPad vs macOS.

Comment: Thanks - that was just an example to show the problem with a few simple lines of code. Using AsyncImage doesn't make any difference to the issue.

Comment: Did you actually try using `Image` and initialising it from `UIImage` on iPadOS and `NSImage` on macOS? You can create a convenience init that handles both systems internally.

Comment: The actual code uses UIImage as the app is intended for iPadOS - I run it from within Xcode on the Mac using the "My Mac (Designed for iPad)" destination so that I can use identical code - its when it runs on the iPad that is the problem not the mac

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic. You only show 1 piece of code in your question, which is using `AsyncImage(url:)`, so how are you using `UIImage`?

Comment: OK - I'll redo it - but AsyncImage isn't the problem and there is nothing in the documentation that says the URL for AsyncImage has to be remote

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/asyncimage) clearly states that _"This view uses the shared URLSession instance to load an image from the specified URL, and then display it."_. `URLSession` is used for remote URLs, not local ones, since it's doing networking.

Comment: Code modified as requested

Comment: Why are you using `NSDataAsset`? You should simply be using `UIImage(named:)` to load an image from an asset catalog.

Comment: The raw file is stored as Data in the asset catalog not as an image